# python real time plot of serial port data has huge lag

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to read from serial port and plot the data in graph using matplot.
Following is my code :
I see that because of plot, there is huge lag (data in queue goes up to 10000 bytes) hence i dont see real time plot coming. Can you please help me if i am doing anything wrong.

<

```
import serial # import Serial Library
   import numpy  # Import numpy
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

   Accelerometer= []
   COM_read = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=None,parity='N',stopbits=1,rtscts=0) #Creating our serial object name
plt.ion() #Tell matplotlib you want interactive mode to plot live data
cnt=0
COM_read.flushInput()
COM_read.flushOutput()
def makeFig(): #Create a function that makes our desired plot

    plt.title('My Live Streaming Sensor Data')      #Plot the title
    plt.grid(True)                                  #Turn the grid on
    plt.ylabel('Acc in g')                          #Set ylabels
    plt.plot(Accelerometer, 'ro-', label='Accelerometer g') #plot the temperature
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')                    #plot the legend
    plt.ylim(15000,30000)                           #Set limits of second y axis- adjust to readings you are getting


print "came through"
while True: # While loop that loops forever
    print COM_read.inWaiting()
    while (COM_read.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
            pass #do nothing
    s  = COM_read.readline() #read the line of text from the serial port
    decx = int(s[0:4],16)
    decy = int(s[5:9],16)
    decz = int(s[10:14],16)
    if decx > 32768:
          decx = decx - 65536;
    if decy > 32768:
         decy = decy - 65536;
    if decz > 32768:
         decz = decz - 65536;
    #print decx,decy,decz
    res = ((decx*decx) + (decy*decy) + (decz*decz))**(1.0/2.0)




    Accelerometer.append(res)                     #Build our Accelerometer array by appending temp readings

    drawnow(makeFig)                       #Call drawnow to update our live graph
    plt.pause(.000001)                     #Pause Briefly. Important to keep drawnow from crashing

    cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt>50):                            #If you have 50 or more points, delete the first one from the array
        Accelerometer.pop(0)               #This allows us to just see the last 50 data points
```

>
----------------Based on Dr.John's suggestion, the code is written as follows -----

```
import serial
import matplotlib
import threading, time
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

    class MAIN:
    #ser =0;
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = 0.0
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=None,parity='N',stopbits=1,rtscts=0)
        self.ser.flushInput()
        elf.ser.flushOutput()
        c = self.ser.read(1);
        while(c != '\n'):
            =self.ser.read(1)
    return

    def acquire_data(self):
        s = self.ser.readline()
        decx = int(s[0:4],16)
        decy = int(s[5:9],16)
        decz = int(s[10:14],16)
        if decx > 32768:
            decx = decx - 65536;
        if decy > 32768:
            decy = decy - 65536;
        if decz > 32768:
            decz = decz - 65536;


    self.res = ((decx*decx) + (decy*decy) + (decz*decz))**(1.0/2.0)
    print self.res
    return

ex = MAIN()
threading.Timer(2,ex.acquire_data).start() #starts function acquire_data every 2 sec and resets self.res with 0.5Hz
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time.time(), self.res, 'o-')
print "closed"
```

Comment: what's drawnow?

Comment: For that amount of data and interaction you should probably use [`PyQtGraph`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/), as `matplotlib` is suited for highly customizable high quality plots.

Comment: I tried installing pyqtgraph but i get errors when i try to import pyqtgraph.


      import pyqtgraph as pg
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
      from .Qt import QtGui
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py", line 32, in <module>
       raise Exception("PyQtGraph requires either PyQt4 or PySide; neither package could be imported.")
       Exception: PyQtGraph requires either PyQt4 or PySide; neither package could be imported.



Any idea how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

A while true loop is a bad idea in most cases.

Non-OO-Programming is a bad idea in most cases.

Appending plot-data to lists is a bad idea in most cases (laggy).

Start the data aquisition at defined times with

```
import threading, time
threading.Timer(2, acquire_data).start() #starts function acquire_data every 2 sec and resets self.res with 0.5Hz
```

then instead of the while-loop, please define class based functions for your own benefit:

```
class MAIN:
 def __init__(self):
    self.res = 0

 def acquire_data(self):
    ....
    return self.res
```

and plot with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time.time(), self.res, 'o-')
```

Greets Dr. Cobra

Comment: Thanks Dr.John.
I am not looking for OOPS concept based coding. I need to plot the data within 9600 baud rate, as my serial port is configured to read 9600 baud rate. So the problem that i am facing is by the time plot happens i have queue of data (upto 10000 bytes) which are waiting to read and then process. And since data comes from serial port , i have to append that to list so that i can plot it. not sure why that can be bad idea.
    Please suggest me how i can avoid the lag issue. I can try threading as mentioned  but the point still remains is 9600 baud rate need to be maintained.

Comment: Currently I am in a project with an optical sensor with a 115k baud rate and it is working perfectly fine with matplotlib

Comment: you can speed up data acqisition by self-recursion of a function which contains the acquisition, as it calls itself immediately after performing the acquisition

Comment: you need to  `def acquire_data(self): ... ***aquire data*** ... acquire_data()'

Comment: but avoid recursion depth exceeding!

Comment: Thanks Dr.John. I am new to python coding and i am trying to learn for some of my signal processing tasks on sensors. I need to plot these data in real time for just analysis. because of time crunch i am not able to write OOPS based python code. if you can point me to correct in this code would be very helpful.

Comment: *** because of time crunch i am not able to write OOPS based python code*** could you elaborate this sentence? I dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: Based on your suggestions, wrote the code to acquire and plot as above.
But i dont seem to be getting anything. even my debug prints (such as prints of resultant and prints of closing) are not coming. Is there anything wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: The python shell does not show any prints nor any figures. Infact shell is hung as i had to press CTRL+C to bring shell back.
Please let me know how can i make this working.